# how to get Internet Explorer to default to my youtube red account, to skip ad when playing a youtube video

Tags: windows-7, video, internet-explorer, youtube

When I use Internet Explorer to open a Youtube video, I get the annoying commercial.  I use my YouTube Red account, on my iPhone, to browse YouTube without commercials.

How can I get IE to automatically use my YouTube Red account, so that the ads get skipped?

Comment: Are you sure it's logging into your Google account?

Answer (score 1):

Things to check:

1. Make sure IE saves cookies for Youtube, Google and Google Accounts
2. Make sure your main Google Account is the one you use for YouTube Red by selecting it in the dropdown menu to choose the right account from a YouTube page.

Comment: if you have 2 accounts and the red one is not being selected by default, try signing out of both accounts, and then sign back into the red one first